# pointer value used where a floating point value was expected

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, floating-point

I keep getting this error:

```
pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
```

And I just can't understand why. I'm sure its easy. I just am so tired and can't connect the dots, my brain keeps micro napping. If a fresh pair of eyes can have a look, and just explain to me as to why I'm having this issue. Thanks.

Oh and the error is regarding the: `payment = (float)paymentInput;` lines.

```
void purchaseItem(VmSystem * system)
{ 
    char purchThis[ID_LEN+NULL_SPACE];
    printf("Please input ID of item you wish to purchase: ");
    fgets(purchThis, ID_LEN+NULL_SPACE, stdin);
    printf("\n");

    Node * previousNode, * currentNode;

        previousNode = NULL;
        currentNode = system->itemList->head;
        while(currentNode != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(purchThis, currentNode->data->id) == 0)
            {
                if(currentNode->data->onHand > 0)
                {
                    char paymentInput[4];
                    float payment;
                    float itemValueFloat;
                    long itemValue;
                    float remaining;
                    float change;
                    /*
                    float validDenom = 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5;
                    */


                    long x = currentNode->data->price.dollars;
                    long y = currentNode->data->price.cents;

                    itemValue = (x*100)+y;

                    itemValueFloat = (float)itemValue;
                    itemValueFloat = itemValueFloat/100;
                    printf("Item value in cents is: %ld cents.", itemValue);

                    printf("You have selected \"%s   %s\”. This will cost you $%.2f.\n", currentNode->data->name, currentNode->data->desc, itemValueFloat);

                    printf("Please hand over the money - type in the value of each note/coin in cents.\n");
                    printf("Press enter on a new and empty line to cancel this purchase:\n");
                    printf("You still need to give us $%.2f:", itemValueFloat);
                    fgets(paymentInput, 4, stdin);

                    payment = (float)paymentInput;

                    checkDenomValidity(payment, itemValueFloat);
                    itemValueFloat = itemValueFloat*100;

                    while(itemValueFloat - payment > 0)
                    {
                        remaining = (itemValueFloat - payment)/100;
                        itemValueFloat = remaining;
                        printf("You still need to give us $%.2f: ", itemValueFloat);

                        fgets(paymentInput, 4, stdin);
                        payment = (float)paymentInput;

                        checkDenomValidity(payment, itemValueFloat);
                        itemValueFloat = itemValueFloat*100;

                    }
                    if(itemValueFloat - payment <= 0)
                    {
                        change = (itemValueFloat - payment)*-1; 
                        change = change/100;
                        printf("Thank you. Here is your %s, and your change of $%.2f.\n", currentNode->data->name, change);
                        printf("Please come back soon.");
                    }

                    currentNode->data->onHand--;
                    break;
                } 

                else
                {
                    printf("OOPS! SORRY, WE ARE SOLD OUT OF THAT ITEM,\n");
                    printf("Please select a different item: ");

                    fgets(purchThis, ID_LEN+NULL_SPACE, stdin);
                }


                break;

            }

            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }

        if(currentNode == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }

        readRestOfLine();
        return;
}
```

This is the function also having the error:

```
float checkDenomValidity(float payment, float itemValueFloat)
{
    char paymentInput[4];

    while(payment != 1000 || payment != 500 || payment != 200 || payment != 100 || payment != 50 || payment != 20 || payment != 10 || payment != 5)
        {
            payment = payment/100;
            printf("Error: $%.2f is not a valid denomination of money.", payment);

            printf("You still need to give us $%.2f:", itemValueFloat);
            fgets(paymentInput, 4, stdin);

            payment = (float)paymentInput;
        }
    return payment;
}
```

Comment: `char paymentInput[4];` and you are trying `payment = (float)paymentInput;` after `fgets(paymentInput, 4, stdin);`? How is `float` and `char [4]` the same?

Comment: Aside: `char paymentInput[4];` is very tightwad, suggest making it `char paymentInput[20];`

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/25058619/694576 holds for `float` as well. Just replace `strtod()` by `strtof()`.

Comment: How could this condition ever be FALSE? `while(payment != 1000 || payment != 500 ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use casting to cast `char[]` to a float.
Use `atof()`.

Comment: Or better `strtof` so you actually have some form of error checking available.

Comment: omg. i knew it was something easy :'D thanks David i will try it now.