# Read a file line by line and scan each character seperated by comma into seperate variables in C

Tags: c, file-io

Have to read file.txt with format as mentioned below:
12AA,abc12 \n 
4CCC,cde15 \n

I want to read the file line by line and store comma separated values in separate variables.

```
fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

while(fgets(buffer, 255, (FILE*) fp)) 
{
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s", acc_no, package);
    printf("%s\n", acc_no);
    printf("%s\n", package);
}

fclose(fp);
```

I would like not only just read and print the variable but, also, to store them in separate variables. Suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: strtok may help.

Comment: so, if every line is a variable, you can read before the whole file and, after, you can use `malloc` to allocate all the variable in the *heap*. Bring the pointer back to the beginning of the file and perform the operation of storing the string in the variable you have allocated. That's all, nothing more! (Be careful: if you need a value and not a string, you need to convert them using the function of the C library: `strod(...)` is one of them - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951019/how-to-convert-string-to-float)

Comment: This [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell):  `while(fgets(buffer, 255, (FILE*) fp))`  **Why** are you casting something that should already be a `FILE *` to a `FILE *`?

Answer (score 3):

`strchr()` can help:

```
while (fgets(str, sizeof str, fp)) {
    char *arr[2], *ptr;

    arr[0] = str;
    if ((ptr = strchr(str, ','))) {
        arr[1] = ptr + 1;
        *ptr = '\0';
    } else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("<%s> <%s>\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
}
```

Notice that you may need to strip the trailing newline lefted by `fgets()` or ommit the `\n` in `printf`

If you need to store those strings in fresh memory, then there is a bit more of work, you can `realloc()` or use a linked list (always prefer linked lists when you don't know the number of lines before-hand):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
};

/* Returns a pointer to an allocated string */
extern char *strdup(const char *);

/* Insert a node and returns a pointer to the data */
static void *enqueue(struct node **root, void *data)
{
    struct node *node;

    if (root == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    if (node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (*root == NULL) {
        node->next = node;
    } else {
        node->next = (*root)->next;
        (*root)->next = node;
    }
    node->data = data;
    *root = node;
    return data;
}

/* Delete a node and returns a pointer to the data */
static void *dequeue(struct node **root)
{
    struct node *node;
    void *data = NULL;

    if (root == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    node = *root;
    if (node != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
        data = node->data;
        if (*root == node) {
            *root = NULL;
        } else {
            (*root)->next = node->next;
        }
        free(node);
    }
    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    char str[256];
    char **arr;
    char *ptr;

    /* While we don't hit EOF */
    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        /* Reserve space for 2 pointers */
        arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 2);
        if (arr == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* If we find a comma */
        if ((ptr = strchr(str, ','))) {
            /* Store the second string */
            arr[1] = strdup(ptr + 1);
            if (arr[1] == NULL) {
                perror("strdup");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            /* Strip the string */
            *ptr = '\0';
        /* If we don't find a comma */
        } else {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* Store the first string */
        arr[0] = strdup(str);
        if (arr[0] == NULL) {
            perror("strdup");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* Add a node to the queue*/
        if (enqueue(&head, arr) == NULL) {
            perror("enqueue");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    /* While nodes in queue show the data and free */
    while ((arr = dequeue(&head))) {
        printf("%s %s", arr[0], arr[1]);
        free(arr[0]);
        free(arr[1]);
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, it is a complete answer. To add some comment in the code to explain what you do (for newbies) may be an added value

Comment: @Leos313, yes, added some comments (even if the function names are pretty descriptive :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fscanf format strings instead.

```
fscanf(fp, " %[^,\n], %[^\n]", values[i][0], values[i][1]);
```

Like so

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    char values[1000][2][100];

    int i = 0;
    while(!feof(fp)) {
      fscanf(fp, " %[^,\n], %[^\n]", values[i][0], values[i][1]);
      printf("%s %s\n", values[i][0], values[i][1]);
    }   

}
```

#### The `fscanf` format string:

- `<space>` = skip leading whitespaces (like a newline from the line before)
- `%[^,\n]` = read a string until, but not including, "," or "\n"
- `,` = expect a comma and discard it
- `%[^\n]` = read a string until, but not including, "\n"

`values` is a 2D array of strings, with 1000 rows and 2 columns. Each element is a string of maximum length of 100 chars.

Also, if you use `%m[^,\n]` instead, fscanf will allocate the memory for the string read.