# I made a calculator in C, but i want to fix some bugs regarding scanf

Tags: c, calculator

So i made a calculator in C and it works, but i want to get rid of some bugs and it has to do with scanf.
The problems i encountered are:

1. if i enter 5 5 , both number 1 and number 2 will be 5. Any way i can ignore the space and take the number as 55?
2. if i enter 5c, it will read number 1 as 5 then it will trigger the failsafe (because of the 'c') and close.
3. if i enter a very large number, it will give a false result. Any way i can make a limit of 15 numbers?

I think i have to replace scanf with fgets , but i dont know how to implement this because of how i wrote my code. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_help(void);

int main (void)
{   
    float nr1, nr2, rezultat;
    char operatia;
    int failsafe;                           //failsafe
    print_help();                           //show help

    printf("Salut! Am nevoie de un numar: "); //first number
    failsafe = scanf("%f", &nr1);
        if (failsafe == 1)
        {
            printf("Ok. Mersi!\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("bruh..");
            sleep(2);
            exit(-1);
        }

    printf("Am nevoie de inca un numar: ");     //second number         
    failsafe = scanf("%f", &nr2);
        if (failsafe == 1)
        {
            printf("Haha! foarte buna alegere.\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("bruh..");
            sleep(2);
            exit(-1);
        }                           
    printf("Bun. Ce operatie vrei sa aplic? (scrie doar unul dintre simbolurile prezentate mai sus)\n Raspunsul tau: ");    //asking for the operation symbol           
    scanf(" %c", &operatia);          

    switch (operatia)                       //------calculare------
        {
            case '+':
                rezultat = nr1 + nr2;
                break;
            case '-':
                rezultat = nr1 - nr2;
                break;                                  
            case '/':
                if (nr2 == 0)
                {
                    printf("nah man. im out.");
                    sleep(2);
                    exit(-2);
                }
                rezultat = nr1 / nr2;
                break;
            case '*':
                rezultat = nr1 * nr2;
                break;
            default:
                printf("bruh..");
                sleep(2);
                exit(-1);   
        }

            printf("Rezultatul tau este: %.2f", rezultat);   //afisare 
            sleep(1);                                        //
            printf("\r\nThank you and...");                  //
            sleep(1);                                        //afisare rezultat
            printf("Goodbye!");                              //
            sleep(3);                                        //
    return 0;
}   
//-----------behind the scenes-----------
void print_help(void)
{
    printf("-----------------------------\n\r");
    printf("\tCalculator v1.2\r\n\r\n");
    printf("-> simbolul pentru adunare este:  +   \r\n\r\n");
    printf("-> simbolul pentru scadere este:  -   \r\n\r\n");
    printf("-> simbolul pentru inmultire este:  *   \r\n\r\n");
    printf("-> simbolul pentru impartire este:  /   \r\n\r\n");
    printf("-----------------------------\n\r");

    return;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `double` instead of `float`, and change `scanf("%f", &nr1);` to `scanf("%lf", &nr1);` If you want to read `"5 5"` as `"55"` you'll have to process the input yourself.

Comment: Why would it be better to use ```double``` instead of ```float```? Is the precision and more memory worth for such an example like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fgets` to read the input as the string. Then, get the number or whatever you want with this string. Using `scanf` can not read whole the line of input because it read word by word from the input.

For removing space character in string you can see [Removing Spaces from a String in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726302/removing-spaces-from-a-string-in-c).

For converting the string to float you can use `strtof` function. See more at [How to convert string to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951019/how-to-convert-string-to-float)

The small example for you to get input string and do something you want with it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void remove_spaces(char* str) {
    const char* temp = str;
    do {
        while (*temp == ' ') {
            ++temp;
        }
    } while (*str++ = *temp++);
}

void copy_str(char *str) {
    const char* temp = str;
    int i = 0;
    while (isdigit(*temp)) {
        str[i] = *temp++;
        i++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    float number;
    char str[30];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    remove_spaces(str);
    int len1 = strlen(str);
    printf("remove_spaces: %s\n", str);
    copy_str(str);
    int len2 = strlen(str);
    if(len1 > len2+1) {
        number = strtof(str,NULL);
        printf("FALSE -- number = %f\n", number);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("copy_str: %s\n", str);
    if(strlen(str) > 15) {
        printf("too long\n");
        return 0;
    }
    number = strtof(str,NULL);
    printf("number = %f\n", number);
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

The output 1: string contents space character.

```
55 55                                                                                                                     
remove_spaces: 5555                                                                                                       

copy_str: 5555                                                                                                            
number = 5555.000000                                                                                                      
Hello World
```

The output 2: string contents alpha character.

```
55 55c                                                                                                                  
remove_spaces: 5555c                                                                                                    

FALSE number = 5555.000000
```

The output 3: string is too long.

```
123456789101111111                                                                                                      
remove_spaces: 123456789101111111                                                                                       

copy_str: 123456789101111111                                                                                            
too long
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by `Weather Vane` you can change the data type read and therefore increase the maximum number!

I suggest reading the Wikipedia page on C data type to pick the type you're most interested in and which fits your needs the most!
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)
If you need to store even bigger numbers you will need to implemented your own solution like storing an array of `preferred_data_type` for example.

To my knowledge, `scanf` doesn't allow parsing `5 5` as `55`.
If you wish to implement this feature you will need to fetch the input from the command line as a string and then parse it yourself :(

This is a simple implementation of the desired behaviour using `getline` for parsing `int`s.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *number;
    ssize_t response;
    unsigned int j = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    printf("> ");
    response = getline(&buffer, &n, stdin);
    number = calloc(1, strlen(buffer) + 1);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; buffer[i]; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] >= '0' && buffer[i] <= '9') {
            number[j] = buffer[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("The number you entered: %d\n", atoi(number));
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
➜  Desktop ./a.out
> 5 5     
The number you entered: 55
➜  Desktop
```

Comment: Thank you so much!